# Multiple Series in HighStock navigator Angular

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, series, navigator

I have Highstock graphics with an array of series objects.  I d'like to display all my series into navigator. By the way, I use Angular.js and ng-Hghicharts.
I saw that solution is to add series after chart generation.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple series in navigator, you need to use workaround with `addSeries` functions.

```
window.chart.addSeries({
        name : "",
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 1,
        type: "line",
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data : new_data,
        showInLegend:false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fFwM/

Comment: I didn't get any result with your method, but i tried to push my series and it worked. But when I zoom in by reducing scrollbar, data are stretching. How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Please recreate both examples (unworking with my solution) and your current as lvie demos on jsfidddle.net

Comment: It's a little part of big project, so it's a bit difficult to reproduce on jsfiddle.net, but thanks for the help provided.
As writing this, i thought that it might be a issue from ng-highcharts.